Floor jack sinking into asphalt driveway
2010 Silverado 1500 extended cab; 5,000 lbs.
I use a 3.5-ton floor jack to lift a single wheel of my truck off of the ground. The jack wheels sink into the asphalt driveway; the asphalt is 2-3 years old.


The asphalt divots in the photo were caused by the larger front wheels of the jack. But the smaller rear wheels of the jack dig in, too.
Problems:

Damage to the driveway.
Jack wheels might not roll as freely as they should, causing a safety issue since the jack should roll as it is raised/lowered.
Possible instability/tipping on soft asphalt material, causing a safety issue.

Question:
What can I do to prevent the jack wheels from sinking into the soft asphalt?
For example, I could put the jack on a 1/4 in. Mild steel plate. (edited; concerns about the plate removed)

maybe the jack could slide out of position. I thought your point is that the jack must be able to slide, so that its bearing point does not slip. I've used scissor and bottle jacks that don't slide, and as the vehicle rises, they get ever more pecarious, sometimes in danger of tipping, collapsing.

Something else to remember about asphalt is the jack stand can sink into just like the wheels of your jack were depending on how it is made. While this doesn't pose a real danger for the person or vehicle, it sure does leave HUGE divots in the asphalt. A piece of board big enough to support all three or four legs  (depending on the manufacture) of the jack stand will keep this from happening.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Good point. Even jack stands that have plates as feet still sink into the asphalt. https://i.sstatic.net/GUhjJSQE.png https://www.princessauto.com/en/4-ton-jack-stands-with-safety-pin/product/PA0009040049

Asphalt is a plastic material, in the engineering sense of the word. Temperature plays a big part of that characteristic, but it's also not a practical one to consider in your application.
It's the distribution of weight from the jack to the surface below it that determines the divots. Quarter inch steel will possibly flex/bend, but in the process, the forces will distribute over a greater area under the steel.
If your vehicle is properly blocked, the jack cannot roll when the lift is in process. The jack itself must roll to compensate for the angular change of the lift point in relation to the pivot of the lift arm. If the vehicle is not properly blocked, you should not be lifting it in this manner.

If the jack is lifting the vehicle from the side, it runs sideways as the angle of the vehicle increases, while the vehicle is blocked from forward/backward movement. I think OP's point is there is a danger that the bearing point of the jack will slip, unless the jack can roll.

I believe that is correct and that the steel will provide suitable distribution of force to allow the jack to roll, but not in a dangerous manner.

I don't think I'm following this line: "If your vehicle is properly blocked, the jack cannot roll when the lift is in process." If the vehicle is properly blocked (aka using wheel chocks), are you suggesting using a jack is dangerous? I'm jacking up a front wheel by placing the jack at the side of the truck, behind the front wheel, jacking up the frame. I observed the jack rolling, as expected. I don't t think I understand how blocking would effect jacking from the side of the truck. It's not like the jack can push the truck sideways. But of course, I might be missing something. Thanks.
